# Rename multiple field values in one statement

Tags: r

I know that it is possible to do the following:

```
df$V1[df$V1 == "Y"] <- 1
```

to rename any value that is equal to "Y" to be changed to 1. However what If I had values that equal "N" that I want to change to 0?

I have tried doing this:

```
df$V1[df$V1 == c("Y","N")] <- c(1,0)
```

but I get a warning

```
longer object is not a multiple of shorter object
```

which leads to not all values that match case definition to be converted.

what would be the way to do this?

Comment: Maybe you should look at `factor` and `levels`?

Comment: (Or, if it's just "Y" and "N", just `as.numeric(df$V1 == "Y")`)

Comment: why don't you try `df$V1[df$V1 == "Y"] <- 1` in a first step and `df$V1[df$V1 == "N"] <- 0` in a second step?

Comment: @Markus it's just a preference. I could do it like that of course, but if there is a way of doing it in one command I would much prefer that

Comment: Here's quite awkward solution `x[x %in% c("Y","N")] <- (0:1)[as.numeric(factor(x[x %in% c("Y","N")]))]` (assuming `x` is `df$V1` and that `df$V1` isn't a factor)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is why your code didn't work

`df$V1[df$V1 == c("Y","N")] <- c(1,0)`

is asking R to match values of V1 where it is a vector of 2 value of "Y" and "N"
if you want to get either "Y" or  "N", you can do

`df$V1[df$V1 %in% c("Y", "N")] <- c(1,0`

In your case, I might consider using factors in R. Factors are categories. Levels in the factors is like a summary of the vector, telling you what unique values/factors are in the vector. The function `levels(x)` gives you the level of vector `x`

So if you have a vector that looks like this : `x<-c('Male', 'Male','Male','Female','Female','Female')`

you will see that it is made out of 2 repeated items `'Male', 'Female'`

if you run `levels(x)`

you will get

```
[1] Male Male Male Female Female Female
levels: Male Female
```

and when you run `levels(x) <- c('M','F')`

you'll get

```
[1] M M M F F F
levels: M F
```

For instance, if you have a given the following dataframe :

```
V1 <- rep(letters[1],10, letters[4],8) ## first column consist of 10 'a' and 8'd'
V2 <- 1:18
df <- data.frame(V1, V2) 

levels(df$V1) <- c('A','D') # replace all 'a' with 'A' and all 'd' with 'D'
```

I think this is the platonic way to do replacement.

Another way if you will want to only replace specific value, I will suggest you to write a function that works like a hash, and do apply over the dataframe.

This technique is used in ggplot to replace labels in facet_wrap http://www.cookbook-r.com/Graphs/Facets_(ggplot2)/

But this means you will end up writing more lines of code although I think it will appear nicer

Comment: ahh yes, the %in% function is key I see. That is so simple. I see what you mean about asking to match a vector.  could you explain a bit more how that last line in the factors bit works? I understand that I have levels in my data which I want to change each one, but I don't see how the last line changes lower case 'a' to upper case 'A'

Comment: @brucezepplin Done! Hope this will help you better understand

Comment: thanks so much. the levels() output makes sense in renaming now. thank you.

Answer (score 1):

`chartr` could be useful:

```
x <- c("Y","N","N","X")

chartr("YN", "10", x)
#[1] "1" "0" "0" "X"
```

Of course this only works if you only have one-character strings.

Answer (score 0):

Best to write reproducible code to begin with. One answer is:

```
df <- data.frame( V1 = c("Y","Y","N"))
df$V1 <- ifelse(df$V1 == "Y", 1,  ifelse(df$V1 == "N", 0, "X") )
```